# how to check multiple substring in a string in perl

Tags: perl

I have a input file which I am reading into a hash table, The input file is as below

```
MANAGEMENT=IDL
NORTH=IDL,NORTHERN||VIDL,NORTH||IDL,NORTH
SOUTH=IDL,SOUTHERN||CIDL,SOUTH
```

Now for each key I have to check if another string say instance (This is also a string) contains the value i.e for NORTH

```
Condition= TRUE if 
$instance contains (IDL AND NORTHERN) OR (VIDL AND NORTH) OR (IDL AND NORTH)
```

Please note that Value can many such OR conditions

I have such 15000 instances against which I have to compare each value so need a fast method.

I was thinking of passing the value to a function which would return a regex against which I can check but  haven't been able to think of any such (I am new bee in perl)

Appreciate any help or better suggestions

Comment: Sorry I edited it is NORTH; pretty new in perl so i wanted to see if there are some quick methods i could use.

Comment: @mpapec  $instance is a string

Comment: no it is contains like I wrote above; to elaborate ( $instance contains IDL AND $instance contains NORTHERN ) OR   ($instance contains IDL AND $instance contains NORTH)

Comment: sounds like you can have other rules than the example; what format are those in? do you only use one rule per run of the program? what are some other actual examples of rules?  what do you actually want to happen based on the rules?  e.g. are you trying to find all those lines for which the rule is true, or divide the lines into those for which it is true or false or just output the result of the rule with the line?

Comment: @ysth I am trying to identify the instances for which the rule is true. The format is the same just that the value can be any thing separate by a || conditions. In case the instance (string I am comparing against) matches both first key and second I will take the second but I am achieving that using a HASHMAP here in this function I just want to identify those which match each of these individual rules and add those which pass to a hash map.

Comment: so you have multiple rules in a single run of the program and the rules are just code, not data?

Comment: @ysth Yes I have the data using which i have to create the final output, $instance though is a set of strings which will vary from 1000 to any number which as of now stands at 15000

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can build multiple hash maps for your indexes. That is, build `%IDL`, `%NORTH`, and `%NORTHERN`. In each of these hash maps, a string will be present if it contains the appropriate substring. That way, your evaluation for a string `$s` becomes:

```
$IDL{$s} && $NORTHERN{$s} || $IDL{$s} && $NORTH{$s}
```

Of course this condition can be shortened to:

```
$IDL{$s} && ($NORTHERN{$s} || $NORTH{$s})
```

Answer (score 0):

From the very little I have go to on here, I'd say you could do:

```
if ( $instance =~ /(?=.*idl)(?=.*north(?:ern)?/ ) {
    print "$instance\n";
}
```

In the above code I am using a lookahead assertion. What it is saying is to match any line that contains both IDL and NORTHERN.

Comment: Thanks a lot @user847388 but that was just an example it can change, also I can have multiple OR conditions or no OR condition.